# how can I extend a property wrapper in swift to add a setter

Tags: swift, generics

I want a property wrapper to mimic the properties of the underlying wrapped value.

I want to have the wrapper to be read-only if the underlining backing store is read-only and writable if the backing store is writable. The end goal is to have the property wrappers that are composable via the decorator pattern, but will warn the calling code if they try and set a value when the innermost struct or class has read-only values.

I tried to add a setter using a extension as follows but it did not work

```
public protocol Gettable {
    associatedtype Value
    var value: Value { get }
}

public protocol Settable: Gettable {
    var value: Value { get set }
}

@propertyWrapper
public struct Wrapped<Store: Gettable> { 
    var store: Store
    public init(_ store: Store) {
        self.store = store
    }

    public var wrappedValue: Store.Value {
        get {
            return store.value
        }
    }
}

extension Wrapped where Store: Settable {
    public var wrappedValue: Store.Value {
        get {
            return store.value  
        }
        set {
            store.value = newValue
        }
    }
}

struct With: Settable {
    var value: Int = 0
}

struct Has: Gettable {
    var value: Int { 5 }
}

class Context {
    @Wrapped(With(value:5)) container
    @Wrapped(Has()) source

    func doSomething() {
         let value1 = source
         let value2 = container
         container = 5  /// throws error 'container is get-only property
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think property wrappers can do this. Perhaps the new macros can, but I haven't played with them yet...

Comment: I could do a cast to Settable but I would be losing Type information

Comment: I think @Sweeper is right here. For example, `#Preview` macros can handle both `UIViewController` and SwiftUI `View`, despite them being completely different types

Comment: Possible approach for now: just create 2 separate property wrappers, one for Gettable, second for Settable